# Linking to vulkan in nim

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, glfw, vulkan, nim-lang

I'm having trouble figuring out how to link more complex libraries to a nim program. Given the following include directories (seperated to different lines):

```
C:\Users\[user]\Documents\visual studio 2015\Libraries\glfw-3.2.bin.WIN32\lib-vc2015;
C:\VulkanSDK\1.0.13.0\Source\lib32;
C:\Users\[user]\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Libraries\glfw-3.2.bin.WIN32\include;
C:\VulkanSDK\1.0.13.0\Include\
```

And this additonal library search directory (same as the first one above):

```
C:\Users\[user]\Documents\visual studio 2015\Libraries\glfw-3.2.bin.WIN32\lib-vc2015;
```

With this code:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
//#include <stdio.h>

GLFWwindow* init() {
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan window", NULL, NULL);

    int extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL, &extensionCount, NULL);

    //printf("%d extensions supported\n", extensionCount);

    return window;
}

void close(GLFWwindow* window) {
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}

int shouldClose(GLFWwindow* window) {
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
}

void pollEvents() {
    glfwPollEvents();
}

int main() {
    GLFWwindow* window = init();

    while (!shouldClose(window)) {
        pollEvents();
    }

    close(window);
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio 2015 with the properties set correctly from the top I can run it and it will open a blank window.

What needs to be done to make the equivilant code run in pure Nim? I have thoughts on how I could do it by compiling with gcc not VS15 as the visual C compiler is too restrictive it seems.

I've wrote the following nim code to try link a dll from VS15 without the main function in it:

```
{.link: "VulkanTest.dll".}

proc pollEvents() {.importc, dynlib: "VulkanTest.dll".}
proc init(): pointer {.importc, dynlib: "VulkanTest.dll".}
proc close(window: pointer) {.importc, dynlib: "VulkanTest.dll".}
proc shouldClose(window: pointer): cint {.importc, dynlib: "VulkanTest.dll".}

var window = init()

while shouldClose(window) != 0:
    pollEvents()

close(window)
```

but it simply says it cannot open the file (the dll).

Is there stuff I need to enter on the command line to get it to work? e.i. `-l` and `-p` (every use of -p I could think of didn't work, even after reversing the slashes and changing the `;` seperators after the urls to be unix style `:`)

What is the equivilant of putting the `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN` before the `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` for the nim compiler?

Comment: `--passC`, `--passL`, `--cincludes`, `--clibdir` and `--clib` seem to be appropriate for C code. Anyway show the sequence of commands **you** use for compile+link. And original text of the error. ;; Update your VulkanSDK ;; You would add configuration macros by e.g. providing it as `-D` parameter to the `gcc` or in VS properties or in the source code as you already have it.

Comment: I switched to linux and compiled my c code into a .so file (and changed the .dll bit to .so everywhere). I added the pragma `{.passC: "-I/usr/lib/glfw-3.2.1/include -I/usr/lib/VulkanSDK/1.0.30.0/x86_64/include".}` now it is saying the lines in my c code from glfw and vulkan are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> but it simply says it cannot open the file (the dll).

That means the file `VulkanTest.dll` is not available in the search path of the compiler you use as backend (VC). You can try and add the path the dll is located at with `--passL:"/LIBPATH:path"` where `path` is the path to the folder containing the dll.

> What is the equivilant of putting the #define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN before the #include  for the nim compiler?

It is unnecessary because all `GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN` does is to include the Vulkan header. But you need to declare the procs you want to call on the Nim side. There is a [GLFW3 wrapper](https://github.com/ephja/nim-glfw) and a [Vulkan wrapper](https://github.com/nimious/vulkan) which do that for you, but I believe the Vulkan wrapper is rather experimental.